# Reading a file contains lists of values into an array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a big text file which is an output of some codes and it contains lists of numbers. The format of the lists in the file is as following

```
[  11.42102518    3.3538624   231.82137052  352.12777653]   [  12.68274035    2.84982539  292.99135783  331.74058558]   [  11.34657161    3.38423623  265.82486527  335.52547905]   [  12.74354078    3.57487634  241.38692542  322.61793392]   [  12.34540891    7.43226428  241.87210696  364.56618065]   [  12.11139764    4.19664745  239.1656334   321.70798174]   [  12.78659285    5.29236544  232.36062356  315.21861344]   [  12.69345477    3.21991939  285.64027138  356.25664941]   [  12.50813292    3.81440083  277.67523696  334.8178125 ]   [  13.1380115     2.84102649  270.39461828  357.04828265]   [  14.07759576    2.32715376  287.91432844  326.39725223]   [  11.85596781    4.0823778   290.16288598  353.67141937]   [  15.40525653    2.91725879  261.31334931  362.72949817]   [  15.01504576    2.46403931  275.26133082  333.77638185]   [  15.28245578    2.98091548  247.72494962  311.64421065]   [  13.49572046    2.52735399  265.58225678  332.79688739]   [  12.82575874    3.98127768  230.90060671  312.34328907]   [  16.76159178    4.02880401  281.66098464  320.10349045]
```

after each 500*20 lists there is a new line `\n` separation.

I would like to read them into **a numpy array** of `Nx4`. I do not know the exact number of existence lists in the file. How can I do it?

Comment: Well what do they represent? Are these list separate rows and are they always containing the same number of elements? Also are there any carriage returns in this file?

Comment: @EdChum They are outputs of a Monte Carlo Markov Chain code namely `emcee` and all the lists have the same length, four number of elements. The code generates in each iteration 20*500 lists of elements and appends to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the input file contains unknown numbers of lists of lists, where each list contains 20 lists with 4 elements and I would like to read all of them into an array with 4 columns, the best approach I came across so far to combine all the lists and make a big array with 4 columns is as following:

```
f = open('sampler_chain.dat').read()

ndim=4
import numpy as np
import re
pattern = re.compile("^[0-9]")
data = np.zeros((1,ndim),float)
i=0;dl=[]
for x in f.split(): 
      if pattern.match(x):
         m = re.match(r"(\d+)\.(\d+)", x)
         x=m.group(0)
         print x
         if ((i/4==0) and (i%4<4)):
            data[i/4,i%4]=float(x) 
         elif ((i/4>0) and (i%4<4)):
              dl.append(float(x))
         if (i%4==3) and (i/4>0):
             data=np.append(data,[dl],axis=0)
             dl=[]
         i+=1
      else:
         continue
```

The problem is that this method is not fast enough to read a huge file of data ...

Answer (score 1):

This code will store all the numbers in one array!! im not sure if thats what you actually wants ! :)

```
  fh = open('text.txt').read()

  pattern = re.compile("^[0-9]")
  _array = []

  for x in fh.split():
      x = x.replace(']','')
      if pattern.match(x):
          _array.append(float(x))
      else:
          continue

  fh.close()
  print(_array)
```

Comment: there are couple of things wrong with your answer first it doesn't return an array. second the elements in `_array` list are `string` and then the last it returns a big entangled list of lists.

Comment: Sorry for that bro ... try it now

Comment: Hey @Dalek if you think that solve your question would please mark my answer as a right answer!! Thank you :)

Comment: No I don't think so because it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: thats impossible .. what do you get when you run it?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need remove [,] from start and end of file. Second, split in on arrays, and last step split elements and put in array buffer.

```
buff = []
for line in open("file.txt"):
    for arr in line[1:-1].strip().split("]\t[") 
        row = []
        for el in arr.strip().split("\t")):
            row.append(float(el))
        buff.append(row)
```